# How do I change the 2 span contents within a button component in react styled with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I would like to create a button component that uses html as below.

```
<button class="button_57" role="button">
   <span class="text">Button</span>
   <span>Alternate text</span>
</button>
```

I want to be able to use one Button component created with react.

`<CustomButton {...otherProps}>{children}</CustomButton>`

Is there a way to modify the span contents within Button component with props like so?

`<Button span_content1={''} span_content2={''}></Button>`

I've only found passing spans as children to work.

```
<Button>
   <span class='text'>Button</span>
   <span>Alternate text</span>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using React we could create a component like this

```
function ButtonName({ content1, content2}) {
   return(
      <Button>
         <span class='text'>{content1}</span>
         <span>{content2}</span>
      </Button>
   )
}
```

After creating the component we can call the Component Name like this.

`<ButtonName content1="Button" content2="Alternate text" />`

To change the content, we can replace the content1 and the content2 with other values

Answer (score 0):

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

// Define your styled component
const CustomButton = styled.button`
  // Add your styles here
`;

const Button = ({ span_content1, span_content2, ...props }) => (
  <CustomButton {...props}>
    <span>{span_content1}</span>
    <span>{span_content2}</span>
  </CustomButton>
);

// Use your component
<Button span_content1="Button" span_content2="Alternate text" />
```

Button component that accepts span_content1 and span_content2 as props and uses them as the content for the two span elements. The rest of the props (...props) are forwarded to the CustomButton component.

https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Comment: I want to be able to use the Button component for other styles of button as well that might not use <span>, which is why I want to avoid using <span> directly in the Button component. My best solution was to pass <span> as children whenever I use such style that requires <span>. Will this be the only solution?